# How to find the reason for frequent occurrence of WHEA Uncorrectable error

Tags: windows-10, crash, vagrant

Since past few days, My system is crashing frequently always with the same error WHEA-Uncorrectable Error. I found online that, it is something related to hardware might be due to overclocking or heating & mini-dump would help us recognize the error.

I have installed a tool call *WhoCrashed* to debug the error & got this, which I didn't understand.

```
crash dump file: C:\WINDOWS\Minidump\021016-20640-01.dmp
This was probably caused by the following module: hal.dll (hal!HalBugCheckSystem+0xCF) 
Bugcheck code: 0x124 (0x0, 0xFFFFE00038C05028, 0xFE000000, 0x1001152)
Error: WHEA_UNCORRECTABLE_ERROR
file path: C:\WINDOWS\system32\hal.dll
product: Microsoft® Windows® Operating System
company: Microsoft Corporation
description: Hardware Abstraction Layer DLL
```

I suspect [vagrant](http://vagrantup.com/) for this error cause everytime the system crashes, an instance of vagrant was running in the background. Sometimes, the system crashed exactly while booting up the vagrant. I have gone a day without vagrant & as expected system didn't crash.

How do I find what is exactly causing this error? How do I solve this? I have been using vagrant since over a year without a single crash.

Comment: share the file C:\WINDOWS\Minidump\021016-20640-01.dmp and I can look at it with a debugger

Comment: Hi, Here it is http://1drv.ms/1PNOano . Thanks!

Comment: Vagrant is nothing more than a front-end to VirtualBox or VMware, it doesn't run anything in background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the output of Windbg:

```
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

WHEA_UNCORRECTABLE_ERROR (124)
A fatal hardware error has occurred. Parameter 1 identifies the type of error
source that reported the error.

Debugging Details:
------------------


DUMP_CLASS: 1

DUMP_QUALIFIER: 400

BUILD_VERSION_STRING:  10586.63.amd64fre.th2_release.160104-1513

SYSTEM_MANUFACTURER:  ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC.

SYSTEM_PRODUCT_NAME:  X550LC

SYSTEM_SKU:  ASUS-NotebookSKU

SYSTEM_VERSION:  1.0       

BIOS_VENDOR:  American Megatrends Inc.

BIOS_VERSION:  X550LC.303

BIOS_DATE:  09/30/2013

BASEBOARD_MANUFACTURER:  ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC.

BASEBOARD_PRODUCT:  X550LC

00 nt!KeBugCheckEx
01 hal!HalBugCheckSystem
02 nt!WheaReportHwError
03 hal!HalpMcaReportError
04 hal!HalpMceHandlerCore
05 hal!HalpMceHandler
06 hal!HalpMceHandlerWithRendezvous
07 hal!HalHandleMcheck
08 nt!KxMcheckAbort
09 nt!KiMcheckAbort
0a 0x0

3: kd> !errrec ffffe00038c05028
===============================================================================
Common Platform Error Record @ ffffe00038c05028
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Record Id     : 01d163df0240ccba
Severity      : Fatal (1)
Length        : 928
Creator       : Microsoft
Notify Type   : Machine Check Exception
Timestamp     : 2/10/2016 16:48:03 (UTC)
Flags         : 0x00000000

===============================================================================
Section 0     : Processor Generic
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Descriptor    @ ffffe00038c050a8
Section       @ ffffe00038c05180
Offset        : 344
Length        : 192
Flags         : 0x00000001 Primary
Severity      : Fatal

Proc. Type    : x86/x64
Instr. Set    : x64
Error Type    : Cache error
Operation     : Instruction Execute
Flags         : 0x00
Level         : 2
CPU Version   : 0x0000000000040651
Processor ID  : 0x0000000000000003

===============================================================================
Section 1     : x86/x64 Processor Specific
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Descriptor    @ ffffe00038c050f0
Section       @ ffffe00038c05240
Offset        : 536
Length        : 128
Flags         : 0x00000000
Severity      : Fatal

Local APIC Id : 0x0000000000000003
CPU Id        : 51 06 04 00 00 08 10 03 - bf fb da 7f ff fb eb bf
                00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
                00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00

Proc. Info 0  @ ffffe00038c05240

===============================================================================
Section 2     : x86/x64 MCA
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Descriptor    @ ffffe00038c05138
Section       @ ffffe00038c052c0
Offset        : 664
Length        : 264
Flags         : 0x00000000
Severity      : Fatal

Error         : ICACHEL2_IRD_ERR (Proc 3 Bank 5)
```

Your CPU has a L2 Cache issue (`ICACHEL2_IRD_ERR`).

Try to [update the BIOS/UEFI to version 403](https://www.asus.com/support/Download/3/516/0/8/AYu12WTkYZXlQcxW/41/) because you still use an older version 303:

```
BiosVersion = X550LC.303
BiosReleaseDate = 09/30/2013
SystemManufacturer = ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC.
SystemProductName = X550LC
```

If this doesn't fix it, the CPU is damaged and need to be replaced (if this is possible for this ultrabook).

Comment: Thanks @magicandre1981 for clear instructions & the link , especially.  Will follow that.

Comment: Upgraded bios to 403 worked. Its not crashing anymore. Thanks magicandre for the magic tip. :)

Comment: nice to hear this :)