# Blue screen and restart of my computer - what reasons?

Tags: windows-10, bluescreenview

My computer from few months have got a problem which now became more frequent.
The symptoms are blue screen or restart of operating system which happen suddenly.
Now this is happening few times per day.

Together with blue screen I got errors which are different, but two of them appear more often:
"whea uncorrectable error"
and "k mode exception not handled"

My operating system is Windows 10 and I have reinstalled it recently. Moreover I got all updates for Windows and updated graphic card drivers as well as motherboard.

What this can be caused by ? Any hint or suggestion ?

Maybe someone have fixed this issue already ?

Regards

Comment: "k mode exception not handled" would hint at a device driver bug (or a bug in something else that runs in kernel space, or affects kernel space code directly). Are all your drivers, anti-virus software, firewall and similar programs up to date? Have you installed anything like that new in the last few months? What about firmware (BIOS/UEFI), does your motherboard manufacturer offer updated versions there? Issues in normal, user-mode software should never cause a modern general-purpose OS to crash; the effects of that should always be limited to the malfunctioning application.

Comment: Regarding the WHEA Uncorrectable Error, you may be interested in [How to find the reason for frequent occurrence of WHEA Uncorrectable error](https://superuser.com/q/1038141/53590), but note that the accepted answer is rather specific; it might point you in the right direction, but you'd likely need to do some analysis yourself.

Comment: Thank you for very quick answer. It gave me some hint to read about. I am thinking to reinstall another Windows on this computer - 8.1.